# how many ways can we arrange As, Bs, and Cs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can we arrange

1. $3$ As, $2$ Bs, and $5$ Cs with no restriction?

$$P(3,2,5) = \frac{10!}{3!2!5!}$$

2. $2$ As, $4$ Bs, and $3$ Cs in such a way that the $2$ As are one next to the other?

I am considering the AA as one symbol:

$$P(1,4,3) = \frac{8!}{1!4!3!}$$

3. $5$ As, $2$ Bs, and $6$ Cs in a way that between the $2$ Bs there are exactly $3$ letters.

The position of the first B determines the position of the second one

$$P(5,1,6) = \frac{12!}{5!1!6!}$$

4. $3$ As, $4$ Bs, and $5$ Cs in a way that not all $5$ Cs are one next to the other.

All the arrangements:  $$P(3,4,5) = \frac{12!}{3!4!5!} \tag{1}$$

5C's together:  $$P(3,4,1) = \frac{8!}{3!4!1!} \tag{2}$$

solution $= (1)-(2)$

5. $10$ As, $6$ Bs, and $5$ Cs in such a way that there are no Bs one next to the other.

Total          $$P(10,6,5)= \frac{21!}{10!6!5!}  \tag{1}$$

$2$ Bs together  $$P(10,4,1,5) = \frac{20!}{10!4!1!5!}  \tag{2}$$
$4!$ corresponds to the remaining Bs and $1!$ to the group BB.

$3$ Bs together $$P(10,3,1,5)= \frac{19!}{10!3!1!5!}  \tag{3}$$
$3!$ corresponds to the remaining Bs and $1!$ to the group BBB.

$4$ Bs together $$P(10,2,1,5)= \frac{18!}{10!2!1!5!}  \tag{4}$$
$2!$ corresponds to the remaining Bs and $1!$ to the group BBBB.

$5$ Bs together $$P(10,1,1,5)= \frac{17!}{10!1!1!5!} \tag{5}$$
$1!$ corresponds to the remaining Bs and the other $1!$ to the group BBBBB.

$6$ Bs together $$P(10,1,5)= \frac{16!}{10!1!5!} \tag{6}$$
$1!$ corresponds to the group BBBBBBB.

Solution $$(1) - [(6)+[(5)-(6)]+[(4)-(5)-(6)]+[(3)-(4)-(5)-(6)]+[(2)-(3)-(4)-(5)-(6)]$$
$$ = (1) + (3) \times (6)+ (2) \times (5) + (4) - (2)$$

Can somebody check, especially the last question?

Comment: I used inclusion-exclusion and found (1) + (3)x(6)+ (2)x(5) + (4) - (2) but i am not quite sure that it is correct

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. If you can answer one variation of the question, you just need to adjust your strategy to answer the other variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solutions to the first, second, and fourth questions are correct.

> In how many ways can be arranged $5$ As, $2$ Bs, and $6$ Cs in such a way that between the two Bs there are exactly three letters?

There are a total of $5 + 2 + 6 = 13$ positions.  Since there must be exactly three letters between the two Bs, the first B must be in one of the first nine positions.  Once the position of the first B is selected, the position of the second B is also determined.  That leaves $11$ spaces in which to place the $5$ As and $6$ Cs.  Choosing which $5$ of these $11$ spaces will be filled with As completely determines the arrangement since the Cs must fill the remaining six positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{9}{1}\binom{11}{5}$$
such arrangements.

Your count is too large since you have not restricted the position of the first B to the first nine positions.

> In how many ways can we arrange $10$ As, $6$ Bs, and $5$ Cs so that no two of the Bs are next to each other?

We could use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to solve the last problem, but we would have to account for all the ways we could have one or more pairs of consecutive Bs.  By only considering how many Bs were consecutive, you overlooked cases in which there are consecutive Bs in separate blocks such as AABCABBACCABBBAAACAAC.  Also, when you apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, you first subtract cases with a pair of consecutive Bs, then add cases with two pairs of consecutive Bs, then subtract cases with three pairs of consecutive Bs, and so forth until you exhaust the restrictions.

An easier method is to first arrange the $10$ As and $5$ Cs in a row, then insert the Bs in the $16$ spaces this creates, $14$ between successive letters and $2$ at the ends of the row so that no two of the Bs are consecutive.

There are
$$\binom{15}{10}$$
distinguishable ways to arrange $10$ As and $5$ Cs in a row since selecting which $10$ positions will be filled with the As also determines which five spaces will be filled with the Cs.  In each such arrangement, there are $16$ spaces in which to place the Bs, where $L$ represents a letter and $\square$ represents a space in which a B could be inserted.

$$\square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square$$

To ensure that no two of the six Bs are consecutive, we select six of these sixteen spaces in which to insert a $B$, which can be done in
$$\binom{16}{6}$$
ways.

Hence, there are
$$\binom{15}{5}\binom{16}{6}$$
arrangements of $10$ As, $6$ Bs, and $5$ Cs in which no two of the Bs are consecutive.

Comment: You state at the beginning that: [...] `The first B must be in one of the first 10 positions` [...] If we place B at position No.10 then there is only space for 2 consecutive letters and position No.13 will be a B again which violeits the question's constraints. Shouldn't the first B have only 9 possible options ? I would appreciate you explaining it a bit.

Comment: @VaggelisManousakis  You are correct.  Well spotted.